# Issue while submitting Jobs in Sqoop2 Client API

Tags: hadoop

Am using Hadoop-2.2.0 on two node cluster, hadoop is configured correctly and working fine , Now am trying to install sqoop 2 (sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200) on it and when am trying to access sqoop 2 web UI (like localhost:12000) am getting the following .

Apache Sqoop ROOT

And when try to access cloudera.com:12000/sqoop/version   am getting following
HTTP Status 404 -
And when I use this in sqoop client

```
[stratapps@cloudera2 ~]$ sqoop.sh client
Sqoop home directory: /usr/local/sqoop2
Sqoop Shell: Type 'help' or '\h' for help.



sqoop:000> set server --host cloudera.com --port 12000 --webapp sqoop
Server is set successfully
sqoop:000> show version --all
client version:
  Sqoop 1.99.3 revision 2404393160301df16a94716a3034e31b03e27b0b
  Compiled by mengweid on Fri Oct 18 14:15:53 EDT 2013
Exception has occurred during processing command
Exception: com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException Message: GET http://cloudera.com:12000/sqoop/version returned a response status of 404 Not Found
```

My  catelina.proparties file for common.loader looks like

```
common.loader=
${catalina.base}/lib,
${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,
${catalina.home}/lib,
${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,
${catalina.home}/../lib/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/tools/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*.jar
```

my  Sqoop.proprties file `org.apache.sqoop.submission.engine.mapreduce.configuration.director`y looks like

```
# Hadoop configuration directory
org.apache.sqoop.submission.engine.mapreduce.configuration.directory=/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/etc/hadoop
```

Please share your input I goggled a lot on this but dint find any solution yet.

Thankyou,
Malleshwar

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting hostname of sqoop server to cloudera.com ? Use you machine's host address, where sqoop server is running . In case you are using a single machine, then change cloudera.com to localhost.